# slick.js: Slider Arrows and Dots not appearing on WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, slick.js

Having a difficult time trying to decipher this. Recently, I took over two websites. Both use the same custom coded WordPress theme. Recently, I changed one of the hero areas to a slider using the pre-existing slick.js script the previous developer installed. After I did that, the left and right arrows, nor the dots would appear. They're supposed to appear dynamically like at http://dermalinfusion.com/. The code it would generate would be something like:

```
<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" type-"button" data-role="none" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: block;"></button>
```

However, on https://envymedical.com, they simply don't appear at all. I changed around the settings in the plugins.js file because I saw arrows: was set to false, but no luck there either. Here's the code:

```
jQuery('.block-heroslider').each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var $imagesSlider = $this.children('.hero-images-slider');
    var $blurbsSlider = $this.children('.hero-blurbs-slider');

    $imagesSlider.slick({
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        asNavFor: '.hero-blurbs-slider',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true
    });

    $blurbsSlider.slick({
        asNavFor: '.hero-images-slider',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true
    });
});
```

The slider does overall work. It does move from slide one to two and back again every few seconds. I'd just to figure out why the navigation does not appear.

NOTE: I should mention we've got a ZenDesk script running that somehow is throwing an error. I deleted that code from my header.php file in my WP theme and after reloading the page, the arrows still do not appear. So that is not the cause.

Comment: you have an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` in console which points out that there is a line break in the javascript code `o.write( '<body onload="document._l();">
' ), o.close()` , that is under comments `<!-- Start of dermalinfusion Zendesk Widget script -->`  you should remove all the js related errors first.

Comment: I actually know about that error. The odd thing is in my code in the header.php file, that line break doesn't exist. I just get }, o.write('<body onload="document._l();">'), o.close() on one line. Doesn't make sense.

Regardless, I deleted the code prior to posting that last night and after I did, it didn't change anything. Problem still persists. So that's not the problem. I should have mentioned that in my original post. My bad.